# Stationary Markov Chain $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with initial distribution $\mu$, then $X_n \sim \mu $

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I feel this question is very silly, but I want to make sure I understand all the definitions correct. We consider discrete time and a state space $S$ which we assume to be Polish, where $B$ denotes the Borel-sigma algebra of $S$.

So a Markov chain is stationary if $P(X_{t_1} \in A_1, X_{t_2} \in A_2, ... , X_{t_k} \in A_k) = P(X_{t_1+s} \in A_1, X_{t_2+s} \in A_2, ... , X_{t_k+s} \in A_k)$, where the  $A_i \in B$, $t_i,s \in \mathbb{N}$. The initial distribution is $\mu(A) = P(X_0 \in A)$, so now obviously $P(X_t \in A) = P(X_0 \in A) = \mu(A)$? Since we have to show this as an exercise, I highly doubt that this is already the solution, but I don't see why.

Furthermore, by setting $t=1$ wouldn't that directly imply that $\mu$ is an invariant distribution? Also the transition kernels must be stationary.

Comment: That is not the definition of stationarity but of course if you assume $P[X_t\in A]=P[X_{t+s}\in A]$ for all $A, s, t$ then $P[X_t\in A]=P[X_{0+t}\in A]=P[X_{0}\in A]=\mu(A)$ and therefore $\mu$ is a stationary and invariant distribution on the state space. Finally I don't know what a stationary transition kernel.

Comment: @P.Quinton So for a process $X$ we defined stationarity as $X$ and $X \circ \theta_t$ having the same finite dimensional distributions, where $(X \circ \theta_t)_s = X_{t+s}$, and with stationary transition kernels I mean time-homogeneous transition kernels

Comment: Yes that is correct, but for instance it also means that $P[X_0 \in A_0, X_1 \in A_1] = P[X_1 \in A_0, X_2 \in A_1]$, the condition you mention above does not imply this and is strictly weaker.

Comment: @P.Quinton Ah I see your point, I have to be more precise. I will edit my post. But still, is that then already the solution?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty simple, but you should make sure that you still understand why this really is a proof. Also the part about transition kernels I don't know.

Comment: Alright thanks!!